# Why MainWindow is not closed in a SLOT here

Tags: qt, slot

I am learning Qt from few days. I am developing a simple project for quiz of just 2 questions in `Qt`. In a `MainWindow`, a question with four options as four `RadioButton`s appears. When user clicks on right option, next question should appear as new `Dialog` & previos question must be closed. So, I wrote the `SLOT` as -

```
void MainWindow::on_radiobutton2_clicked()
{
    Dialog q;
    q.exec();
    MainWindow::close();
}
```

But this code doesn't close MainWindow though it opens `Dialog`.

When I changed the sequence of instructions like below, it worked -

```
void MainWindow::on_radiobutton2_clicked()
{
    Dialog q;
    MainWindow::close();
    q.exec();
}
```

So, why `MainWindow` is not closed in first case?

Comment: dont open and close dialogs. Either update the content of one single window or use a QWizard.

Comment: @UmNyobe Will you please tell me how to update the contents of the same window?

Comment: There are many ways. For instance you can put a [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) and switch the visible one.

Comment: Thanks. Learnt something new..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following two lines

```
q.exec();
MainWindow::close();
```

The dialog appears as a modal dialog and blocks the event loop until it is closed. So the main window's `close()` function will not execute unless you close your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the main window likely leads to bad user experience. What you probably want is to show a modal dialog.

Since `QDialog::exec()` blocks until the dialog is closed, you shouldn't use it. Simply `show()` the dialog instead.

```
void MainWindow::on_radiobutton2_clicked()
{
    Dialog * q = new Dialog;
    q->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); // thus it won't leak
    q->setModal(true); // so that the main window doesn't have to be closed
    q->show();
}
```